# Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response. Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud function endpoint which will forward PUT request to another API endpoint. I do have set these `Access-Control-Allow-` headers:

```js
// src/middlewares/enableCORS.ts
export default function enableCORS(
  fn: (req: https.Request, res: e.Response) => Promise<void>
) {
  return async (req: https.Request, res: e.Response) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
      'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    );
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.end();

      return;
    }

    await fn(req, res);
  };
}
```

```js
// src/index.ts
import enableCORS from './middlewares/enableCORS'

export const my_endpoint = https.onRequest(
  enableCORS(async (request, response) => {
    // Forward request
  })
);
```

But I my request from browser still blocked by CORS. Please help.

Comment: Can you please share what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question:

I solved this problem by using esbuild to bundle separated files into a single index.js file.